# how to populate values in listbox based on value entered in textbox in BIRT?

Tags: textbox, listbox, report, birt

I want to populate values in a list box based on a value entered in textbox. It cant be aceived through cascading paramters as all parameters in Cascading parameters are List Boxes. But my requirement is to populate values inside a ListBox based on the value entered inside a textbox. Please help.

Comment: This question is also posted at http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/29914-how-to-populate-values-in-a-listbox-based-on-a-value-entered-in-a-textbox-in-birt/

Answer (score 0):

Cascading parameter is the only way to define a dependency between two parameters. As you can see, the birt web viewer displays a textbox just below each combobox, and a radio button to select if we fill each list parameter from the combobox or the textbox:
[image: textbox under a listbox]

I know some users had exactly the same requirement, and have successfully modified "ComboBoxParametersFragments.jsp" to display only the textbox when it is needed. For example we can use a specific prefix in the parameter name, or a user property, so that we can decide in the JSP if we hide the combobox or not.